# Amazon SNS AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient.Token

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am currently stuck on CreatePlatformEndpointRequest.Token with my Windows Store App. I am not sure where/how to get this token.

I already have my Package SID, Access Key ID, and Secret Access Key

my codes are

```
AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient sns = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient("secret", "secret", RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);

d("creating platform endpoint request");
CreatePlatformEndpointRequest createPlatformEndpointRequest = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest();
createPlatformEndpointRequest.PlatformApplicationArn = "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXXX:app/WNS/AmazonSNS";
createPlatformEndpointRequest.Token = "what token?";

d("endpoint result");
CreatePlatformEndpointResult createPlatformEndpointResult = await sns.CreatePlatformEndpointAsync(createPlatformEndpointRequest);

d("endpoint arn: " + createPlatformEndpointResult.EndpointArn);
```

I get the following error

```
"Invalid parameter: Token Reason: Notification Channel URI is not valid"
```

that's of course of the token I used "what token?" How and where do I get the Token value?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_SimpleNotificationService_Model_CreatePlatformEndpointRequest.htm

> > Unique identifier created by the notification service for an app on a device. The specific name for Token will vary, depending on which notification service is being used. For example, when using APNS as the notification service, you need the device token. Alternatively, when using GCM or ADM, the device token equivalent is called the registration ID.

To manually add a device token or registration ID

1. Go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/sns/, click Apps, click your app, and then click Add Endpoints.
2. In the Endpoint Token box, enter either the token ID or registration ID, depending on which notification service. For example, with ADM and GCM you enter the registration ID.
3. (Optional) In the User Data box, enter arbitrary information to associate with the endpoint. Amazon SNS does not use this data. The data must be in UTF-8 format and less than 2KB.
4. Finally, click Add Endpoints.

Now with the endpoint created, you can either send messages directly to a mobile device or send messages to mobile devices that are subscribed to a topic.

Ref: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-devicetoken.html

Is this helpful?